# How to copy a file into a particular location by making use of msi file?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer

I'm writing a code for installing a software using VC++. So, what I want to do is, I want to copy a *.jar file, which I have, into a particular location when I run the installer. I know that I have to do it using msi. How do I do this? I'm a beginner in VC++.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an installer that makes an MSI file then that install will copy the file to the system and you don't need VC++. If you have an installer tool then say which one if you need help in a certain area, and we can point at tutorials etc for getting started.

Comment: Actually am writing a code in VC++ ,What I have asked above is part of code which i am doing in VC++. I wanted to know how will I create the MSI file that will copy a *.jar file, which I have, into a particular location when I run the installer.